# ajax retrieving all files from a server

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi im having a bit of trouble with an AJAX get call from my server.

The goal is im trying to retrieve all files from a directory on my server to then auto populate them into a js treeview but i keep getting this error:

```
GET http://url/app/webroot/files/?_=1347870792047 403 (Forbidden) jquery.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) index:2095
f.Callbacks.o jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B
```

and the code im using to get the files is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://url/app/webroot/files/",
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            timeout: 100000,

            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) 
            {
                $('#tree1').tree({
                data: data
                });
            }
```

If i specify a file within this folder i can retrieve it but how do i retrieve all the files within this directory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you access http://url/app/webroot/files/ from your web browser, what do you get?

Comment: It says i dont have permissions to access it even though ive logged onto the server and given the folder chmod 777 permissions

Comment: OK you need to fix the permissions error first. If you are using Apache you may need to switch on indexes (google "Option Indexes")

Comment: Ye this was the problem thanks very much but i still cant seem to retrieve all the files from that directory any advice on how to do it?

Comment: Which particular treeview plugin are you using?

Comment: Im using jqtree is has a built in json function but just doesnt seem to work.

Comment: OK - you need to make sure that you are feeding JSON into the treeview, since it depends on the JSON structure to build the tree. The URL that you specify in $.ajax should be returning a JSON string instead of HTML. I doubt the server is processing the filelisting and converting it into JSON automagically for you, so you may need to write some server code to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not only chmod 777 works on all server, for starters check the server log.. also another reason why you might get a (Forbidden) error is due to the users group. Make sure the directory that belongs to to the current user. Some host add this kinda of option, example "1&1 hosting" so.. if

```
[Directory:] (belongs to Santa Clause) 
[Permission:] (777)
```

will not work if you are a Santas little helper :) you have to make it like so..

```
[Directory] (Santas Little Helper)  
[Permission] (777)
```

using chown -R (try doing this on the server, or ftp) than try again. Hope this can solve the problem. Also you might try `dataType: script` and see how that goes. As a side note, you might need a server side scripting to pull all files of a directory.. yet I could be wrong.. I have never tried this before really... it seems kinda dangerous, yet it also depends on the environment.